# Connecting SAS and FTP server(or network drive)

Tags: sas

I'am completly new to SAS(and all these techincal things), but **i need connect a network drive (or FTP?) to SAS**, so i can copy or send files to it. I guess, it should look like another server at a workspace or something. I only know the address of it(maybe it will give you some clue):

`\\10.48.42.166\exportsexternal1\oaDiez0Naf`

The problem is even in that i don't know how to google it correctly - all link's are mainly about `FILENAME in FTP`

Comment: Hint: if you look at the description of your two tags, those are VERY different things that both get referred to as SAS.  You should first figure out which one you want and correct the tags / write out the acronym on first use.. and then you may want to post it to serverfault anyways because this is possibly Off topic as written on stack overflow

Comment: Is SAS running on the same server as where you want to read/write data?  Said another way, if you plan on reading & writing to 10.48.42.166, is SAS also running on 10.48.42.166?

Comment: @Amw5G No.  10.48.42.166 is a shared folder, and SAS is running on a server

Comment: You need to map map network drives at an OS level.  SAS doesn't support access FTP sites as a library (I'm guessing that's because because FTP doesn't properly support sequential or random access to a file).